# Axios response array

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the following code

```
export const backend = {
  listAll: () => {
    let collection = [];

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000", {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}})
      .then(response => response.data.forEach(entry => collection.push(entry)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log("result: ", collection, collection.length;
    return collection;
  }
}
```

The console output is:

```
result:  Array [] 0

(expanded array)
[]
​
0: Object { identity: "1580db04-4329-48c5-8d0f-e6b47be5cb90", name: "aaa" }
​1: Object { identity: "2227b700-1cbd-4635-ad9f-de18a552a686", name: "bbb" }
​2: Object { identity: "c47cedcc-be16-4806-9f8d-865c9bbec8f7", name: "ccc" }
​3: Object { identity: "e07953a9-dbfa-4ff1-ad8b-4797879ba7f3", name: "ddd" }
​4: Object { identity: "e4b25633-3bea-4ab0-aa07-7e7a03df3a52", name: "eee" }
​5: Object { identity: "f96a54ac-ebb3-494b-a5e2-2407a936e465", name: "fff" }
​
length: 6
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

So the console output is telling me that `collection.length` is zero, but the expanded array show me the correct content. The calling code receives an empty array. Why the array is empty?

Comment: You have a asynchronous function, you need to the log inside of promise (then) .then(response => { response.data.forEach(entry => collection.push(entry)); console.log(collection); } )

Comment: The main point here is that the calling function is getting an empty array...